# JAVA получить несколько переменных из строки

Tags: java

Есть строка, которая формируется таким образом:

```
out.write("AUTH:"+"LOGIN:"+login+":PASS:"+pass +"ENDAUTH" +"\n");
```

как итог получаю текстовую строку `AUTH:LOGIN:moiLogin:PASS:moiPass:ENDAUTH`
как из можно проще и лучше обработать эту строку, чтобы `moiLogin` и `moiPass` были присвоены двум переменным `String login;` `String pass;` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы разбить строку на несколько токенов:

```
String[] result = s.split(":");
```

где **s** - полученная/прочитанная строка. Далее **moiLogin** будет находиться в третьем токене (он же 2-й индекс) **result[2]**, а **moiPass** в пятом токене (он же 4-й индекс) **result[4]**, то есть:

```
login = result[2];
pass = result[4];
```